# Unity Trail Renderer is getting connected to non-existing point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having an issue with Unity `Trail Renderer`. I'm expecting trail to appear only when moving finger, but instead I also get straight line connecting the end of last trail to the beginning of a new one. Is this a visual bug in simulation or expected result of my code?

First of all, I have `Weapon` object with corresponding script `Weapon.cs`, where the position of rigidbody of said object is dictated by `touch.position`:

```
public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{  
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0) 
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) 
            {
                rb.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have `Trail Renderer` Component on the `Blade` which is a child object of `Weapon`. In `Blade.cs` I use `Trail.Clear()` to remove all existing points of `TrailRenderer` when user ends `Touch`. I checked the size of trail array on `Touch.Began` but it was empty as expected so there is no reason for `TrailRenderer` to connect these points. I also tried to play around with `Trail.emit` but the result was the same.
Here's the `Blade.cs` script:

```
public class Blade : MonoBehaviour
{
    private TrailRenderer tr;

    void Start()
    {
        tr = GetComponent<TrailRenderer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0) 
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) 
            {
                tr.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Also, worth mentioning that I am using Simulated Touchscreen from `com.unity.inputsystem`.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any chance this is because your `tr.Clear()` call is concurrent with your `rb.position()` function, meaning your re-positioning co-occurs with the clearing instead of after it?

Comment: @Juris Don't think so, `rb.position()` is called during `TouchPhase.Moved` and `tr.Clear()` is called after moving has ended, during `TouchPhase.Ended`. Even if I change `Moved` phase to `Began` - Trail gets teleported anyway.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding trail renderer takes transform.position as first point for trail. When you touch screen first time, you set second point with ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);

In my case (i'm using solution based on https://github.com/Brackeys/Fruit-Ninja-Replica) i'm setting blade position in startCutting() method and move it very close to first touch point before I start drawing trail.